# Android IME back button is hide my keyboard and EditText of Twitter app

Tags: android, twitter, keyboard

I've made a custom soft keyboard extended from `InputMethodService` class, when the user clicks on any EditText, my keyboard will be shown and fill the whole screen (portrait or landscape).

Once I open Twitter application to write a tweet, writing Tweet screen shows up and my keyboard will be shown with no problems.

[image]

Once I click back button to hide the keyboard and back to write tweet screen, the keyboard and tweet screen have gone as well! So, any text I've written using my keyboard will be also gone.

I'm not sure if this is Twitter app problem, but I'm not sure how can I solve that? Even if I could handle back button event, what should I do next?

If you also using any soft keyboard, once you click back button, it will hide the keyboard and write a tweet screen as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a small trick for that, write a text and remove it to get the focus when `onWindowShown` is called:

```
 getCurrentInputConnection().commitText(" ", 1);
 getCurrentInputConnection().deleteSurroundingText(1, 0);
```

Now everything is working fine :)